# Views 7.3.1.3 ajax error

Tags: views, ajax

I am running a 7.41 with [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) 7.3.1.3 version and editing views causes ajax error?

here is the current error code :

```
an ajax http error code.
http status :500
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seven","theme_token":"L0_2m6Pw1Y-YlW1YH8Xlfc_C0oFxmC1n0tPxBJZyDLA","jquery_version":"1.10"},
"artPortfolio":{"art_portfolio-block_1":{"columns":"3"}},"better_exposed_filters":{"views":{"art_portfolio":{"displays":{"block_1":{"filters":[]}}}}},
"viewsImplicitFormSubmission":{"views-ui-preview-form":{"defaultButton":"preview-submit"}},
"ajax":{"preview-submit":{"wrapper":"views-preview-wrapper",
"event":"click","progress":{"type":"throbber"},
 "method":"replaceWith","url":"\/admin\/structure\/views\/view\/art_portfolio\/preview\/block_1\/ajax","submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"op","_triggering_element_value":"Update preview"}}},
"urlIsAjaxTrusted":{"\/admin\/structure\/views\/view\/art_portfolio\/preview\/block_1\/ajax":true,"\/admin\/structure\/views\/view\/art_portfolio\/preview\/block_1":true}},
"merge":true},
```

Why is this happening in this version? Do I need to downgrade, or is it due to the [jquery_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module? I tested on the following jquery versions :

- 1.5
- 1.7.2
- 1.8
- 1.9
- 1.10 
  but all are not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HTTP 500 errors should mean that you have a more useful error message in your web server logs. Can you post the error log message?

Comment: What rooby said. Sometimes these can stem from running out of memory on complex Views. But look at the logs (maybe watchdog is a good place to start)

Comment: checked on the watchdog nothing appearing when that is being triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rooby is right, this views happen because of the server not providing enough memory limit to run it and that happens, so I solve it when I asked the server guy to add more memory limit to the site and all good, thank you!